# why merging dataframes is not working the way is intended in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

it looks like this

```
            Weight    Height    Depth RepID       Code
0           18         3        14    257428      0
1            6         0         6    214932      0
2           21         6        16     17675      0
3           45         6        20     60819      0
4           30         6        16    262530      0
       ...       ...       ...       ...    ...
4223        36         6        28    331596      1
4224        24         9         0    331597      1
4225        36        12         8    331632      1
4226        24        24         0    331633      1
4227        30         9         0    331634      1

[4228 rows x 5 columns]
```

I broke it down in test and training datasets

```
y = df["Code"]
X = df.drop("Code", axis=1, errors='ignore')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=TestSize, random_state=56)
```

then predict the values

```
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

now I want to keep the predicted results along with its related RepID in a file

so i did this

```
   dfCSV = X_test["RepID"]
    dfCSV["Code"] = pd.DataFrame(y_pred)
    dfCSV.to_csv(PredictionFile)
```

expecting the ended dataframe would like this

```
         RepID       Code
0        84833      0
1        38388      1
2         2848      0
3         2992      1
4        28279      0
       ....    ...
423     74993      1
424     39924      1
425     55339      0
426     33882      1
427     64490      1
```

but the result is something to see for the first time is this

```
dfCSV
Out[15]: 
3792                                                262578
482                                                 129648
62                                                    7144
2998                                                127711
840                                                 157391
                       
207                                                 277899
569                                                  89965
2895                                                116296
570                                                 279183
ICD10         0
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
..  ...
Name: RepID, Length: 847, dtype: object
```

what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Likely a typo in `dfCSV[Code] = pd.DataFrame(y_pred)`: did you mean `dfCSV["Code"]`?

Comment: yea it was "Code" but some how missed in the copy paste processs

Comment: Also if you did `dfCSV = X_test["RepID"]` then `dfCSV` is a `pd.Series`, not a dataframe. I don't think you can add a column to a series like that. You're going to have to create a dataframe first

Comment: how can i put X_test["RepID"]  and y_pred in a dataframe then?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi this will be a dataframe `dfCSV = X_test[["RepID"]]`, with double brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. Try double brackets in `X_test[["RepID"]]` for `dfCSV` to be a dataframe, then `dfCSV["Code"] = y_pred` to create a new column.

Here's the code snippet with mock data:

```
X_test = pd.DataFrame({"RepID": [0, 1, 2], "Smth": [3, 4, 5]})
y_pred = [5, 6, 7]

dfCSV = X_test[["RepID"]]
dfCSV["Code"] = y_pred
print(dfCSV)
```

Output:

```
   RepID  Code
0      0     5
1      1     6
2      2     7
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided code demonstrates how to combine two columns. I guess it is what you are looking for.

```py
import pandas as pd
data_X = {
    'Weight': [18, 6, 21, 45, 30],
    'Height': [3, 0, 6, 6, 6],
    'Depth': [14, 6, 16, 20, 16],
    'RepID': [257428, 214932, 17675, 60819, 262530]
}
X_test = pd.DataFrame(data_X)
data_y = {'Code': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
y_pred = pd.DataFrame(data_y)
print(X_test)
print(y_pred)
dfCSV = pd.DataFrame([X_test["RepID"],y_pred['Code']]).T
# Another option
# dfCSV = pd.concat([X_test["RepID"], y_pred], axis=1)
print(dfCSV)
```

**Output**

```
   Weight  Height  Depth   RepID                                                              
0      18       3     14  257428                                                              
1       6       0      6  214932                                                              
2      21       6     16   17675                                                              
3      45       6     20   60819                                                              
4      30       6     16  262530                                                              
   Code                                                                                       
0     0                                                                                       
1     1                                                                                       
2     2                                                                                       
3     3                                                                                       
4     4                                                                                       
    RepID  Code                                                                               
0  257428     0                                                                               
1  214932     1                                                                               
2   17675     2                                                                               
3   60819     3                                                                               
4  262530     4
```